# How to delete a folder of the FirebaseStorage in Android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I am using **FirebaseStorage** to store the pictures users upload in my application. But the user has the power to delete them too. And when they do that I want to remove the pictures of the FirebaseStorage as well. For this I have created a folder child in FirebaseStorage and the name of that child is the **authID** of that user. All the pictures he uploads will be stored in that folder specifically. And I want to remove the folder when it's necessary so that the pictures within the folder will be removed too. The picture might clear what I'm trying to say-
[image: Storage Path]

But seems like it's not possible. I saw another similar questions where they said it's not possible for **FirebaseStorage**. But those questions are pretty old. Is it still impossible to do? If so, is there any other ways to do this task? I tried doing this but it didn't work-

```
StorageReference sr = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
                    StorageReference sr2 = sr.child("status").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
                    sr2.delete().addOnSuccessListener(unused -> {
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Status Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    });
```

Is there any way to delete a folder from FirebaseStorage? Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

There is no operation to delete a folder in the Firebase SDK for Cloud Storage. You will have to [list the files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/list-files) in the folder, and then delete each file individually.